# OpenCV failed to create more than one tracker at the time

Tags: c++, opencv, tracker

I faced with strange problem when I trying to declare more than one OpenCV tracker. Code below compiles OK but failed with cv::Exception during execution.

```
// create a tracker object
Ptr<Tracker> tracker_kcf            = cv::TrackerKCF::create();
Ptr<Tracker> tracker_mil            = cv::TrackerMIL::create();
Ptr<Tracker> tracker_goturn         = cv::TrackerGOTURN::create();
Ptr<Tracker> tracker_csrt           = cv::TrackerCSRT::create();
```

No matter how many trackers are declared, if its quantity more than one, code doesn't work. If I'm declaring in addition legacy trackers, sources even cannot compile.
OpenCV 4.5.2 MSVC 2019

Thank you

Comment: When I tried to compile these 3 lines, it compiles and run with no problem. Can the problem something else ?

Comment: Maybe these declarations was optimized without using. I checked and found that code above runs without further init. But it will not work for me if these trackers are used further. Try to add init:
        tracker_kcf->init(frame_kcf, roi_kcf);
        tracker_mil->init(frame_mil, roi_mil);
        tracker_goturn->init(frame_goturn, roi_goturn);
        tracker_csrt->init(frame_csrt, roi_csrt);